# how to call qCompress() in PySide

Tags: python, pyside

Learning PySide. I tried below in my idle IDE to call qCompress() but failed. Can anyone help me?

```
>>> from PySide import QtCore
>>> QtCore.qCompress("test")

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    QtCore.qCompress("test")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'qCompress'
```

Comment: try `dir(QtCore)` see if the attribute is available

Comment: I'm guessing `QtCore` is a package and not a module, and thus you would need to `import from` in order to get `qCompress` (assuming it actually is a function/class and not a module)

Comment: tried dir(QtCore). No, qCompress() is not in QtCore. Does anyone know where qCompress() belows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like PySide haven't added that yet. PyQt4 has this function. The code below works.

**code**

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
print repr(QtCore.qCompress("test"))
```

**output**

```
PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray('\x00\x00\x00\x04x\x9c+I-.\x01\x00\x04]\x01\xc1')
```